# loginbox (iframe) inside another subdomain

Tags: javascript, python, iframe, google-api, facebook-login

What I'm trying to do is get a login box (iframe) available for all my subdomains...

My first attempt was open www.domain.com/login inside one.domain.com... but I get this x-frame sameorigin error because of the subdomain. In this case if I set x-frame options to allow any origin... is this safe?

also I tried to put my login url inside every subdomain so everyone can access login box from one.domain.com/login

the problem is that I'm using GPlus API and it doesn't let me complete my request because of mismatch_origin error... the only thing I can do here is put all my subdomains in Google console....